# getting "pq: syntax error at or near" with Go and sqlx

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE "order"
(
    "order" jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

i try to work with bd with these codes using sqlx:

```
func (r *RepositoryPostgres) CreateDocument(order L0.Order) error {
    tx := r.db.MustBegin()

    orderJSON, err := json.Marshal(order.OrderEntry)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tx.MustExec("INSERT INTO order (order) VALUES ($1)", orderJSON)
    err = tx.Commit()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

```
func (r *RepositoryPostgres) GetAllDocuments() ([]L0.Order, error) {
    var documents []L0.Order

    err := r.db.Select(&documents, "SELECT * FROM order")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return documents, nil
}
```

but im getting error **pq: syntax error at or near "order"**. What is the problem with my syntax?

Comment: Terrible (and reserved) name for a table, you now must use double quotes " every time you query this table: "order". Advice: Change the table name. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: … and the column name

Comment: @FrankHeikens how to name my table and field with orders properly? i am really new to backend, dont even know

Comment: How you name your database tables is entirely your choice - you might use `Orders` - presumably it can contain many not just one - besides if your table is just a single column storing json data a relational database management system is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

"Order" is a reserved keyword, you will need to enclose it in double quotes.
You can see other reserved keywords [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Change your code as follows:

1st Function (Line-7):

```
tx.MustExec("INSERT INTO \"order\" (\"order\") VALUES ($1)", orderJSON)
```

2nd Function (Line-3):

```
err := r.db.Select(&documents, "SELECT * FROM \"order\"")
```

Note: Its a temporary solution, it is better to change the table name.

Comment: Changing the names is the real solution, using double quotes " is just waiting for the next accident.